# Rerender API's image every N second

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Image rerender every N second (user determines value through Slider). Default value=3
Also i want to set initial state for imageUrl, before the component have rendered. How can i do this? And how to handle situation when user didn't connect to the Internet

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(3);
const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState();  

useEffect(() => {
  const valueCopy = value;
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
                .then(responce => responce.json())
                .then(data => {
                    setImgUrl(data.message);
                })
                .catch(err => console.warn(err));
        }, valueCopy * 1000);

   return () => clearTimeout(timer);
});  

return (
   <Image style={styles.img} source={{ uri: `${imgUrl}` }} />
   <Text style={styles.valueText}>{value}</Text>
   <Slider value={value} onValueChange={(sliderValue) => setValue(sliderValue)} />

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(3);
  const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState();

  const getImage = () =>
    fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setImgUrl(data.message);
      })
      .catch(console.warn);

  useEffect(() => {
    getImage();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(getImage, value * 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <div>
      {imgUrl ? <img src={imgUrl} alt="dog" /> : <div>LOADING...</div>}

      <div>{value}</div>
      <input
        type="range"
        min={1}
        max={10}
        value={value}
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit festive-chandrasekhar-hg65z]